# Store and retrieve the array of dictionary values and load it into tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, dictionary, swift2

In Swift.

I want to store this two values the 1.Name and 2.Address these are two text field  which are in single row of table view cell and i have “+” button where i can add multiple entires.

so here what ever the values i have enter in the textfield it has to store locally.

And then the next time when i comes to screen i have to retrieve the data and load into the tableview.

So tried with creating the Array of dictionary with having the key value pair of name and address.

Storage Class:

class StorageModel: NSObject 
    var dict = [String: String]

*) Main Class:

With having the table view delegate and other stuff.

*) TableView Cell:

Which contains the

1. Name text field
2. Address text field.

So how can i implement this functionality. I was stuck on this. Please help me friends. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please show the code that  you tried

Comment: @SubinKKuriakose Hi Subin, I have deleted the code because some where its crashing and i could not able store as well .. the above mentioned details are what i have to implement. Please help me.

Comment: For storing you can use Sqlite (https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift).

Comment: @SubinKKuriakose Thanks . But i have to store the values through creating the models ...

Comment: class UserDetails {
 var Name: String = ""
 var Address: String = ""
}
//tableViewController

var UserDetailsList = [UserDetails]()

for add -> just create an object and fill the value from textfield values you entered . you have to create a method for insert fetch in UserDetails class.
fetch all value when tableview viewdidload or viewdidappear method store to UserDetailsList
create no of rows based on UserDetailsList.count on section  . just try lot of examples available. you should create sqlite db and a table contain fields like model UserDetails.

Comment: @SubinKKuriakose Thanks a lot. I will try.